# PHP　日付の型について

Tags: php

PHPを使っています
入力された年月日から年齢を算出するプログラムを書いているところです。
その際に、入力された年月日が日付の型ではない（例えば1999年15月40日）のようなときに
空で返すというプログラムを書きたいです。

どなたかご教授ください

Answer (score 0, accepted):

正しい日付かを真偽値で返す `checkdate` という関数があるようです。

https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.checkdate.php

実行例:

> ```
> <?php
> var_dump(checkdate(12, 31, 2000));
> var_dump(checkdate(2, 29, 2001));
> ?>
> ```

結果:

> ```
> bool(true)
> bool(false)
> ```

Comment: ありがとうございます。参考にさせて頂きます